# Does perl can send special keys such as F1 under Linux?

Tags: perl, sendkeys

I want to run another script by "F1" from current perl script, How perl send such keys? Can anyone help me? thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

you might like to look at using a curses library for perl.

Comment: thanks for answering, but I need to work under shell, I spent lots of time to find the solution ,unfortunately, I have no progress:(

Comment: Then you may like to look at termios, curses wraps all this up for you.